# Use file pointer in insert mode, not overwrite mode in PHP

Tags: php-7, file-manipulation

I have noticed that in PHP (7.x), when you write to a file, it overwrites any existing characters.  For example,

```php
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r+");

/* test.txt contains
abc123
*/

fwrite($file, "~");

/* test.txt now contains
~bc123
*/

fclose($file);
```

This is a simple example - I could have stored all of the file contents, reopened in write mode, type `~`, type the stored contents, done - but my file is going to become large (meaning variable size), and it contains multiple records, not just one like this example.

What I want is something like this:

```php
$file = fopen("test.txt", "ir+"); // insert mode r+

/* test.txt contains
abc123
*/

fwrite($file, "~");

/* test.txt now contains
~abc123
*/

fclose($file);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: first read the content of file, then you concatenate  "~" with content of file and write it using fwrite($file, "~".$file_content);

Comment: @JackSparrow: as I had said in my question, I will not be able to do that because my file is larger than this example one.  I do not wish to use that solution because, as the file grows larger, it will eventually become too large for that.  I am using this for a project, and at the point when it becomes too large, no one will be able to use it anymore.  It might even crash.  So I am looking for an answer that can perform this operation, without any worries about memory space or anything like that.

Comment: you can read large files line by line as a buffer of certain size using fgets(). Then you can modify line buffer as you need as per your question  and write the buffer to same line.